# Refactoring a method for specific clients

Tags: c#, refactoring, strategy-pattern

Methods specific for customers:

I try to refactore a code, where are a lot of logic for specifi customer:

```
public void SendDocumentsToCustomer(List<Case> cases)
{
    foreach(var case in cases)
    {
        if(case.CustomerId==123)
        {
        if(case.Type==1 || case.Type==2)
        {
        SendDocumentsToCustomer123(case)
        }
        else if(case.CustomerId==456)
        {
        if(case.Type==1 || case.Type==3)
        {
        SendDocumentsToCustomer456(case);
        }
        }
        else if(case.CustomerId==768)
        {
        if(case.Type==2)
        {
        SendDocumentsToCustomer456(case);
        }
        else
        {
        SendDocumentsToCustomer(case);
        }
    }
}
```

The list of specific customer will grow, and the conditions will be modified as well. I will have a generic solution, but maybe code like this with method DoItForClient123 is not a bad solution and I should leave it like that and goint this way introduce methods like CanDocumentsBeSendToClient123 and so on?

I will be very gratefull for some input

Comment: Where is the loop on `cases`? In general, without knowing what you do in `SendDocumentsToCustomer...` it's impossible to tell how you can improve it. So maybe it's possible to use a single method or it's impossible because the process is very different for every customer.

Comment: if (c.CustomerId == 768) smell like ten spirit

Comment: good question Tim. I've corrected the code. The methods SendDocumentsToCustomerXXX make different stuff. For one customer we send thos file with sftp, for some via email, and for some using web service.

Comment: what is the difference from SendDocumentsToCustomer456 to SendDocumentsToCustomer123? Can't you refactorize in the SendDocumentToCustomer(Case c, int customerId)?

Comment: Using indentation certainly wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To separate logic for each specific customer I would use such code:

```
abstract class DocumentSender   //Base class for all document sending components
{
    public abstract bool CanSend(Case @case);        // Check if sender can send the document
    public abstract void SendDocument(Case @case);   // Send the document
}

class DefaultDocumentSender : DocumentSender
{
    public override bool CanSend(Case @case)
    {
        return true;   //Can process all requests
    }

    public override void SendDocument(Case @case)
    {
       // Do something
    }
}

class Customer123DocumentSender : DocumentSender
{
    public override bool CanSend(Case @case)
    {
        return @case.CustomerId == 123;   //Specific case
    }

    public override void SendDocument(Case @case)
    {
        if(@case.Type==1 || @case.Type==2)
        {
            // Do something different
        }
    }
}

//Separate class for getting the correct sender
class CaseSenderFactory    
{
    readonly List<DocumentSender> _senders = new List<DocumentSender>();

    public DocumentSenderFactory()
    {
        //Initialize the list of senders from the most specific. 
        _senders.Add(new Customer123DocumentSender());
        // Add more specific cases here
        _senders.Add(new DefaultDocumentSender());   //Last item should be the default sender
    }

    public DocumentSender GetDocumentSender(Case @case)
    {
        //At least one sender needs to satisfy the condition
        return _senders.First(x => x.CanSend(@case));   
    }
}
```

You then can use the senders like this:

```
var factory = new DocumentSenderFactory();
foreach(var @case in cases)
{
    var sender = factory.GetDocumentSender(@case);
    sender.SendDocument(@case);
}
```

Comment: thanks dotnetom. looks really promising. CanSend of Customer123DocumentSender should be extended with case.CustomerId=123, shouldn't be?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a good ideea to make something like this:
The ideea is if the code is really specific to some of the Customers then you could make a class for them. If the code for specific customers somehow related but combined in a diferent way then you should take a loot at DecoratorPattern(mabye it helps)

```
class Customer
{
    public abstract SendDocumentsTo(Customer c);
}


class SpecificCustomerA
{
    public overwrite SendDocumentsTo(Customer c)
    {
        if (c is SpecificCustomerB)
        {
            //Logic here
        }
    }
}

class SpecificCustomerB { ... }
```

Comment: Often when you see something like `if (c is SpecificCustomerB)` in the code you have a feeling something smells here

Comment: @dotnetom You are right, but as he presented the problem, he said the code is a bit specific to each customer, I just presented a somewhat cleaner approach :)